# How do I get query to give me results of month using url?

Tags: coldfusion

The query below works and gets me the correct results.

```
<cfset month = URL.month>
<cfset year = URL.year>

<cfquery datasource="testing_1" name="allDepartments">
        SELECT CAST(employeedept AS INT) as dept,
        ROUND(AVG(case when rating1>0 THEN CAST(rating1 AS FLOAT) ELSE null END), 2) as q1,
        ROUND(AVG(case when rating2>0 THEN CAST(rating2 AS FLOAT) ELSE null END), 2) as q2,
        ROUND(AVG(case when rating3>0 THEN CAST(rating3 AS FLOAT) ELSE null END), 2) as q3,
        ROUND(AVG(case when rating4>0 THEN CAST(rating4 AS FLOAT) ELSE null END), 2) as q4,
        ROUND(AVG(case when rating5>0 THEN CAST(rating5 AS FLOAT) ELSE null END), 2) as q5

        FROM CSEReduxResponses
        WHERE execoffice_date BETWEEN DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE())-1, 0)
        AND DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, -1, GETDATE())-1, -1)
        AND execoffice_status = 1   
        group by employeedept
        order by employeedept
</cfquery>
```

I want to get the execoffice_date to give me the data for a month ago, which is why I'm
using GETDATE. But if the url changes month=5&year=2014 to month=3&year=2014 it will give me the 
same results in the query the same time.

What I would like to get the query to get the data depending on the url month and year.

How would I accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are given url.year and url.month, this will get you the current month.

```
StartDate = CreateDate(url.year, url.month, 1);
EndDate = DateAdd("m", 1, StartDate);  // you really do want the 1st of next month
```

Use them like this:

```
and execoffice_date >= <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_date" value="#StartDate#">
and execoffice_date < <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_date" value="#EndDate#">
```

For previous months, use date add on those variables.

Comment: thanks, how would i change them so i be able to get data form last month depending of url?

Comment: The answer is in the last paragraph of this answer.